# R Language: Trouble understanding conversion between Discrete time series to time series object

Tags: r, time-series

I am trying to learn R to analyze discrete and unevenly spaced time series for my research. The dataframe has columns "t,y,dy", where t is time in units of days and y/dy is the value/value error. I first downloaded my data and plotted it as shown:

```
ogle <- read_csv("ogle_data/sc49_ogle.csv")
ggplot(ogle, aes(x = t, y = y, ymin = y-dy, ymax = y+dy)) + 
 geom_pointrange() +
 ylim(15.3, 14.3) +
 xlim(57500, 59460)
```

Data ouput is:

```
dput(head(ogle,20))
structure(c(57557.43506, 57560.41181, 57576.4440799998, 57583.3938199999, 
57587.4252200001, 57593.3775300002, 57601.3586300001, 57604.3239899999, 
57611.3208099999, 57617.3240499999, 57621.27972, 57624.29385, 
57629.31177, 57632.2804299998, 57636.28437, 57639.26076, 57646.23569, 
57649.2604999999, 57652.2198200002, 57656.20529, 14.416, 14.403, 
14.418, 14.417, 14.399, 14.401, 14.417, 14.415, 14.408, 14.381, 
14.406, 14.411, 14.403, 14.401, 14.387, 14.394, 14.403, 14.394, 
14.411, 14.404, 0.003, 0.003, 0.003, 0.003, 0.003, 0.003, 0.003, 
0.003, 0.003, 0.003, 0.003, 0.003, 0.003, 0.003, 0.003, 0.003, 
0.003, 0.003, 0.003, 0.003), .Dim = c(20L, 3L), .Dimnames = list(
    NULL, c("t", "y", "dy")), .Tsp = c(1, 1.05205479452055, 365
), class = c("mts", "ts", "matrix"))
```

[image]

This shows the data has some gaps and the time domain for the data ranges from about 57,500 to 59,000. Now, when I convert my data to a time series object I get:

```
Y <- ts(ogle[,2], start = min(ogle[,1]))
plot(Y, ylim = c(15.5,14.3))
```

[image]

As you can see, my new time series does not have the same span in time as the original. It stops around 57,750 rather than 59,000. It appears that the `ts()` function is treating each data point as being equally spaced. How do I fix this such that the time series actually reflects the true data?

Comment: It will make it easier for people to help if you can figure out a way to share part of your data or some made up data with similar properties. Often, including the output of `dput(ogle)` (or if that's excessive, `dput(head(ogle, 50))`) in the text of your question will save other people from doing too much guesswork and redundant prep.

Comment: Just included it, lmk if that works

Answer (score 1):

A `ts()` object in R can only handle regularly spaced observations in time. If you need to use the `ts()` class, you will need to complete the dataset by adding in `NA` values for the time points that are missing. You might be able to do this with your `ogle` object using `ogle %>% expand(t = full_seq(t, 1))` before creating your `ts()` object. Without your dataset, I can't check if this will work.

An alternative would be to use a time series data structure that allows for gaps (implicit missing values), such as `tsibble`.

```r
library(tsibble)
as_tsibble(ogle, index = t)
```

You can learn more about analysing time series data with tsibbles from the FPP3 online textbook: https://otexts.com/fpp3/

Comment: My data is actually a subset of the first three columns of data found [here](http://ogle.astrouw.edu.pl/ogle/ogle4/xrom/sxp6.85/phot.dat)  (there times is just mine plus 2400000).   `ogle %>% expand(t = full_seq(t, 1))` runs into error saying "full_seq applied to object of class function". I'm not sure how to interpret this since R is completely new to me.